# How to distribute an open-source jar with dependencies?

Tags: java, jar, dependency-management, software-distribution

I'de like to distribute a Java package that I've written under some permissive license.

The resulting `speedytools-0.1.jar` has some common Java dependencies like Apache Commons and Guava.

What is the most Java-esque way to distribute this jar? Should I include the dependencies in my distributed zip file?

Comment: Are you packaging your jar with maven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't include dependencies into your jar. Just declare them as maven dependencies.

This will give several advantages:

- Users can use your library in
  conjunction with standalone Guava of any backward compatible version.
- User can reduce dependencies count by excluding Guava transitive
  dependency from your library if he uses parts of your library, that
  don't depend on Guava.

Answer (score 2):

[jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/): "Embedding java libraries since 2004."

- You don't have to worry about your library depending on a specific version of a dependency, which may conflict with the dependencies of another library.
- You can freely change your libraries should you add a dependency in a future release - users won't have to reconfigure their build scripts.
- You can patch the libraries to fit your needs: If you want a special build of one of those common Java dependencies, then hack away - your build doesn't even need to be compatible with the public version.
- **It makes the entire process of downloading and implementing your package exceedingly simple.** The degree to which this is beneficial (or even desirable) depends obviously on what your package is, what it does and who you want it to do it for. Admittedly, I'd favor the maven solution in most of the use-cases I can imagine - but nonethess, I think jarjar definitely has a place in a question as open-ended as this one, as there are certainly still use cases for which it is ideal.

ps great question, looking forward to seeing other answers.

Comment: jarjar is good, but it isn't really answering the question if external dependencies should be included.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl: Can you hear me now? :)

Comment: Yes sir! :) Though I still prefer the maven way in the other answer (depending a bit of the purpose of the jar).